# How can I turn on Vscode formatter in .innerHTML in JS

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Im using custom elements in JS to make components like footer, header etc..
How can I turn on HTML formatting like HTML document in .innerHTML in JS.

I would like to increse my workflow comfort.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your question.  What is your goal.

Comment: You can use this plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nicolasparada.innerhtml

Comment: @mgm793 Thank you! I want exactly this solution!